# Positioning and styling SVG tspans?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am having two issues with this SVG. First, I need it to use the Raleway font. Second, I need the text to be the other way around. I have tried to use CSS translate and rotation, but they did not provide the result I was looking for. I have read up on the documentation for SVG styling, but it was less than helpful and did not cover my particular needs. I have searched through Google as well and they only suggested things that I have already tried.

I have included some code below for reference.

```js
// JavaScript that was graciously provided for me:

const rad = Math.PI / 180;

let cx = 50, cy = 100, R = 50, r = 35, A = 40 , a = 5, o=4;
// o for offset
testGroupC2.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${-90 -(A / 2) - a} ${cx} ${cy})`)


// control points for the quadratic Bézier
let px1 = cx + R * Math.cos(0);
let py1 = cy + R * Math.sin(0);
let px2 = cx + R * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py2 = cy + R * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px3 = cx + r * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py3 = cy + r * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px4 = cx + r * Math.cos(0);
let py4 = cy + r * Math.sin(0);

// points used to draw the shape
let x11 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos(0);
let y11 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin(0);

let x1 = cx + R * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y1 = cy + R * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x2 = cx + R * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y2 = cy + R * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x21 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y21 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x31 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y31 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x3 = cx + r * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y3 = cy + r * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x4 = cx + r * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y4 = cy + r * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x41 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos(0);
let y41 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin(0);

/*
No rounded corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x3},${y3} A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

/*
Beveled corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         L${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

// Rounded corners with quadratic Bézier curves
    d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         Q${px2},${py2} ${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         Q${px3},${py3} ${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         Q${px4},${py4} ${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         Q${px1},${py1} ${x1},${y1}Z`;

testPath2.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 40 100 40">
  <g id="testGroupC2" >
    <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[   
  
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');
     text{font-family:Raleway; z-index: 20}
     
             ]]> 
  </style>
   <path id="testPath2"/>
    <text>
         <textpath style="font-size:4pt;" xlink:href="#testPath2" startOffset="63%" >
            <tspan x="-3" y="10">Home</tspan>
      </textpath>
    </text>
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems like you should add an extra path/curved line inside your shape that follows the middle of your shape horizontally and use that for your text path

Comment: Or use a duplicate of your path, but in reversed order, so the text follows the 'inside' of the shape. (Or just use the bottom part of the path.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the bottom curve and use that as a path for the text. It has to be in reverse order, otherwise (as is the case in your code) the text will show up underneath the path and rotated (which is actually the direction of the path).

So: an extra path just for the text and some adjustments to the text alignment

And here's the result:

```js
// JavaScript Document

const rad = Math.PI / 180;

let cx = 50, cy = 100, R = 50, r = 35, A = 40 , a = 5, o=4;
// o for offset
testGroupC2.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${-90 -(A / 2) - a} ${cx} ${cy})`)


// control points for the quadratic Bézier
let px1 = cx + R * Math.cos(0);
let py1 = cy + R * Math.sin(0);
let px2 = cx + R * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py2 = cy + R * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px3 = cx + r * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let py3 = cy + r * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);
let px4 = cx + r * Math.cos(0);
let py4 = cy + r * Math.sin(0);

// points used to draw the shape
let x11 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos(0);
let y11 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin(0);

let x1 = cx + R * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y1 = cy + R * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x2 = cx + R * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y2 = cy + R * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x21 = cx + (R-o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y21 = cy + (R-o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x31 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos((2*a + A)*rad);
let y31 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin((2*a + A)*rad);

let x3 = cx + r * Math.cos((a + A)*rad);
let y3 = cy + r * Math.sin((a + A)*rad);

let x4 = cx + r * Math.cos(a*rad);
let y4 = cy + r * Math.sin(a*rad);

let x41 = cx + (r+o) * Math.cos(0);
let y41 = cy + (r+o) * Math.sin(0);

/*
No rounded corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x3},${y3} A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

/*
Beveled corners
let d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         L${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         L${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         L${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         L${x1},${y1}Z`;*/

// Rounded corners with quadratic Bézier curves
    d = `M${x1},${y1} 
         A${R},${R},0 0,1 ${x2},${y2}
         Q${px2},${py2} ${x21},${y21} 
         L${x31},${y31}
         Q${px3},${py3} ${x3},${y3}
         A${r},${r},0 0,0 ${x4},${y4}
         Q${px4},${py4} ${x41},${y41}
         L${x11},${y11}
         Q${px1},${py1} ${x1},${y1}Z`;
   
testPath2.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);


/* based on the 2nd A-curve of the testPath,
   but last point and starting point switched,
   as well as the sweep-flag of the curve */
   
    dtext = `M${x4},${y4}
         A${r},${r},0 0,1 ${x3},${y3}`;
         
textPath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",dtext);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 40 100 40">
 <defs><path id="textPath"/></defs>
 <g id="testGroupC2" >
   <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:thin');
    text{
     font-size: 4pt;
     fill: #ffffff;
     text-anchor: middle;
     font-family: 'Raleway';
     z-index: 2;
    }
   ]]> 
   </style>
      <path id="testPath2"/>
   <text>
    <textpath xlink:href="#textPath" startOffset="50%" >
     <tspan x="0" dy="-5.5">Home</tspan>
    </textpath>
   </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, Philip!